# What is the shortcut key to comment multiple lines using PyCharm IDE?

Tags: python, pycharm, comments

In Corey Schafer's *[Programming Terms: Mutable vs Immutable](https://youtu.be/5qQQ3yzbKp8)*, at [3:06](https://youtu.be/5qQQ3yzbKp8?t=186), he selected multiple lines and commented them out in PyCharm all in one action.

What is this action? Is it a built-in shortcut in PyCharm that I can use or configure myself?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is a setting you can change and define in "Settings".

The default is with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for Windows, or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for Mac.

Comment: There are many settings, I cound not find it ... can you please describe a bit more specific where I can change that (Pycharm / Windows)? I suppose it is somewhere in Keymap ("Editor actions") , but could not find the specific entry there. On a German notebook without numeric keypad, it is impossible to use the standard shortcut Ctrl + /.

Comment: It is Keymap -> Code -> Comment Actions -> Comment with Block Comment or Comment with Line Comment

Answer (score 12):

Years later: on AZERTY keyboard, '/' from syntax area (;.:/!§,?), AKA "slash" does not work!
You have to use the '/' symbol from numbers area (division symbol).

Comment: And if you don't have numbers area on laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Is depends on you're text editor , but probably all text editor use **(ctrl + /)** just highlight all the code you need to comments and use the shortcut , to know what shortcut using in you're favorite text editor search in google : *YourTextEditor* shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

For a QWERTY keyboard layout you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad /</kbd> to comment something out

Comment: And if you don't have numbers area on laptop?

Answer (score 2):

this is not the shortcut but an alternative: using 3 single (''') or double quotation marks (""") in the beginning and also at the end of a bunch of lines.

Comment: Answer does not address the question asked

Answer (score 0):

If you use macbook build-in keyboard, this shortcut does not work. So you can assign new shortcut for this purpose by following steps;

1.Go keymap menu

```
PyCharm -> Preferences -> Keymap
```

2.Find "comment with line comment" then click pencil sign "add keyboard shortcut" then assign your custom shortcut (press your favorite keyboard combination)

Answer (score -1):

Highlight the region and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>. This is better than the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> which puts a `#` infront of every line.

Answer (score -2):

This heavily depends on where you're writing your python code. If you're writing it in Notepad, there won't be a shortcut for commenting a line.

However, if you use an IDE, you will probably have such capability alongside the ability to change the shortcut.
Just search Google for keyboard shortcuts for your preferred IDE.

Comment: i'm using PyCharm, but there isn't actual way to do it! but the guy on the youtube does..

Comment: When googling "pycharm keyboard shortcuts", the first result is:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html
I.e for PyCharm the default is `Ctrl+/`.
If you wish to change it up, take a look at (first result on google for "pycharm change keyboard shortcuts"):
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html