# PyCharm CE: Shortcut opens menu 'help' instead of commenting in/out codelines

Tags: pycharm

**Whenever I am using the shortcut `CMD + /` to comment code in or out , it doesn't do that, but opens the *help* menu instead.**

I am using PyCharm CE 2021.3.2 (`Build #PC-213.6777.50, built on January 27, 2022`), installed via `brew install pycharm-ce` on a macOS 12.2.1 (21D62).

Things I checked so far:

- The PyCharm keymap is set to `macOS`, the behaviour also happens with the keymap `macOS System Shortcuts`.
- I have only the default extensions installed
- I looked around online to see if others have the same problem, but couldn't find anything. Just references to the already known `CMD + /` (eg. here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426322/what-is-the-shortcut-key-to-comment-multiple-lines-using-pycharm-ide))
- This case is also **not** listed as a [possible shortcut conflicts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html#conflicts) in the official documentation.
- When using a different editor like Visual Studio Code, the same shortcut behaves as expected, so it does not seem to be a general system override of sort.
- I tried the internal macBook Pro keyboard, as well as an external keyboard, both have the same behaviour.

Appreciate any hints!

EDIT:

- I have the german keyboard layout where `/` is at  `SHIFT + 7`
- `CMD + SHIFT + 7` **is** a system default.
- I can use the `/` on the external Numpad (still annoying)
- And I am not alone, the open issue [IDEA-165950](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165950) is all about it, and 5 years old

Suggested [Intermediate solution](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165950#focus=Comments-27-4605128.0-0) (of sort):

- Activate *Use national layouts for shortcuts* in the preferences
- Use the plugin **Keymap Nationalizer** and *Generate National Keymap*, giving me `CMD + -` instead of `CMD + /`

So my question is answered ... and VSCode seems hard to beat these days.

Comment: Try remapping the hot keys manually and see if it warns you about overriding an existing shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Qumber. If I remove the shortcut to set it again, the editor tells me it's `CMD + SHIFT + 7`, so it must be because of my german keyboard layout (`/` is at `SHIFT + 7` on this layout). And this shortcut actually **is** coming from the system, VSCode is apparently just overriding it. So far, I couldn't find a way to remove it from the systems default. It's still strange, that PyCharm is not listing it under _show conflicts with system shortcuts_ in the preferences.